# How to create a Spring Boot application that only listens to Redis channel and dispatch events?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create a middleware that listens to Redis channel and transform the events, dispatch them to other services. The other services are too old and fragile to touch so this is basically  Adapter Pattern. The `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

The problem is that the app finishes right after I start it. I don't know how to make Spring hang there and keep listening to Redis events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is using a countDownLatch in a separate thread.

```
@Bean
CountDownLatch latch(){
    //Create countdownlatch with 1 countdown
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    //Start thread
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        //Since you are using lombok you can use sneakyThrows, so you 
        // don't have to handle the InterruptedException
        @SneakyThrows
        public synchronized void run() {
            //Hang this thread until counted down
            latch.await();
        }
    }.start();
    return latch;
}

//Then you can autowire into any future bean/component and shutdown 
// whenever you want by calling latch.countDown()
@Bean
String die(CountDownLatch latch){
    latch.countDown();
    return "dead";
}
```